# Potence of Euler's Number

Tags: calculus, limits

Show with help of the Bernoulli Inequality that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{n}=1$$
End with:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=\frac{1}{e}$$

Answer (score 8):

Note that Bernoulli's Inequality says that $(1+x)^n \ge 1+ nx$ if $x\ge -1$. In particular, let $x=-\dfrac{1}{n^2}$. We get
$$1-\frac{n}{n^2} \le \left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n \lt 1.$$
Now use Squeezing to conclude that the limit is $1$.

**Remark:** If we have **defined** $e$ by 
$$e=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n,$$
then we can use the above result to conclude that since
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n,$$
we must have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=\frac{1}{e}.$$

This is a useful step in one approach to defining the exponential function.

Comment: Bernoulli's ineq. must be $\,(1+x)^n\geq 1+nx\,$ . Of course, +1 anyway

Comment: @DonAntonio: Thanks. Such a short answer but still a typo!

Comment: In your last, you show $e = \frac 1e$?!

Comment: @RossMillikan: Thanks. The perils of cut and paste! I copied the third to last displayed formula, with intent to modify. Did not modify enough.

Answer (score 2):

To ask the second question, 
if we can use that 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{a}{n} \right)=e^a,
$$
then 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\left(1+\frac{-1}{n}\right)^{n}=e\cdot e^{-1}=1.
$$